# How do I declare an ID for a ON_COMMAND handler?

Tags: c++, mfc

I make MFC homework.
But It makes errors.

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMFC_Exp01Doc, CDocument)
ON_COMMAND(ID_ARTHMETIC, &CMFC_Exp01Doc::OnArthmetic)
ON_COMMAND(ID_ARITHMETIC, &CMFC_Exp01Doc::OnArithmetic)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

error 2065 says that Declare the word "ID_ARTHMETIC,ID_ARITHMETIC"

I found many sites about MFC ON_COMMAND but it doesn't declare example )ID_0000

How do I declare this word?

```
void CMFC_Exp01Doc::OnArthmetic()
{
    int i, j;
    int temp;
    for (i = 0; i<256; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j<256; j++) {
            temp = m_InImage[i][j] + 40;
            if (temp>255)
                m_OutImage[i][j] = 255;
            else if (temp < 0)
                m_OutImage[i][j] = 0;
            else
                m_OutImage[i][j] = (unsigned char)temp;
        }
    }

    UpdateAllViews(NULL);
}

void CMFC_Exp01Doc::OnArithmetic()
{
    int i, j;
    int temp;
    for (i = 0; i<256; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j<256; j++) {
            temp = m_InImage[i][j] + 40;
            if (temp>255)
                m_OutImage[i][j] = 255;
            else if (temp < 0)
                m_OutImage[i][j] = 0;
            else
                m_OutImage[i][j] = (unsigned char)temp;
        }
    }

    UpdateAllViews(NULL);
}
```

Comment: Seems you are copy-paste code from another project, Take a look at your .rc file and figure out what ID_0000 do then you declare that into the resource files.

Comment: You probably lack basic knowledge about MFC. You won't get very far by just copy pasting code around. There are tons of MFC tutorials out there.

Answer (score 2):

This IDs are simple defines. Usually defined in a file named resource.h

This IDs are created when you edit the UI parts like menus or toolbars. Each command on a toolbar or menu has a separate ID. This IDs for commands are usually in a range >0x8000.

Additional helpful questions: So when you want that a command is handled, that command must be given by a user. How this should be done in your case? Where do you have the UI for this command? Check out if you already have a command ID but may be a different one.